# Nexxt Solution Wireless Router resetting to factory default when I lose power

Tags: passwords, wireless-router, reset

I have a Nexxt Solution 54M Wireless AP Router that resets every time it loses power.If I had changed the name, added a password and modified any other settings, everything goes back to factory default.This should only occur when I press the reset button or perform this tasks in the admin panel of the router.  Is there a way to fix this? could it be a firmware issue of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

I would answer any generic *Device X loses its config on power loss* with the same answer:
Check the on board battery.

There are only a few ways in which a device can remember its settings:

1. Store it in RAM. This lasts until the power is cut. **Usually a small battery provides power to prevent this.**
2. Write it to an EEPROM. These can only be written a limited number of times. And since most devices (not just access points, but also stuff such as VHS recorders) do not do this I assume it to be more expensive.
3. Write it to some location on the network. (Not normal for SOHO devices).